# Should I have used "but" or "and" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

The sentence in question is:

> Why would Aunt X be cold [but/and] not Aunt Y? I thought X was the one
>   who started it?

Which one is more correct?

I opted to change the sentence to read:

> Why would Aunt X be cold instead of Aunt Y? I thought X was the one
>   who started it?

I would still, however, like to know which one is more correct, if not both.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar reaction to bendl, but I'll try to explain it a bit differently.

> Why would Aunt X be cold, but not Aunt Y?

Generally, the conjunction *but* has the same **logical** meaning as *and*, but is used to introduce a statement that nonetheless contrasts with the previous statement or that is somehow unexpected. E.g. the American Heritage Dictionary provides the following definition of *[but](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=but)*: “2. **Contrary to expectation**; yet: *She organized her work but accomplished very little. He is tired but happy.*”

So I would interpret the version of the sentence with *but* to imply the following: *Given that Aunt X is cold, we would expect Aunt Y to be cold.* And this in turn implies that it is possible for both aunts to be cold.
So I would say that the version of the question with *but* does imply that it is possible for both aunts to be cold, but in an indirect fashion.

> Why would Aunt X be cold, and not Aunt Y?

The conjunction *and* doesn't generally create the same sense of contrast. Instead, what this sentence seems to suggest is that *it is arbitrary that one aunt rather than the other aunt is cold.* This is consistent with a situation where it is only possible for one aunt to be cold at a time, although I don't think it *requires* that to be true.

> Why would Aunt X be cold instead of Aunt Y?

I think the word *instead* implies that we are only talking about situations where one aunt or the other is cold, and we aren't going to worry about accounting for the possibility of neither or both being cold.

This version of the question does seem to be vaguer than the version with *but* in one respect: it doesn't clearly indicate whether we would be more likely to expect Aunt X or Aunt Y to be cold. I guess it could be taken to imply that the questioner expected Aunt Y to be cold, but I think the version with *but* has a stronger implication that we would be more likely to expect Aunt Y to be cold.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both are correct, but to my ear (American English, Southeast) '*and*' sounds odd and possibly antiquated. I would also like to note that, in my mind, there is a distinction between the original and your correction: "But not Aunt Y" indicates that one of the two is cold, though either one has the potential to be. "Instead of Aunt Y" implies (to my ear) that Aunt X being cold and Aunt Y being cold are mutually exclusive, and only one could be cold at a time.

Comment: I'm interested in your distinction. Is that your opinion or do you have a reference?

Comment: That is my opinion, a quick search hasn't turned up anything immediately useful on the subject. I'll make that clear in my answer.

Comment: Good idea. I did think about your distinction and I can sort of see where you're coming from. But I suppose the other way round could be equally as plausible.